# Java do while look proper coding?

Tags: java

I am trying to return data from a freaky do while or the if statement loop and it will not return the items I set why?

```
// yesno to n for first loop through.

do {
    System.out.println("Welcome Sales ID: " + salesID + "  please enter the samsung TV sold: \n");
    samsungProduct = scanValue.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter your total TV sales amounts individually for today \n");
    singleSale = scanValue.nextDouble();
    totalSales = totalSales + singleSale;
    totalItems = totalItems++;
    System.out.println("Do you want to enter another sales total(Y/N): \n ");
    yesNo = scanValue.next();

} while (!yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));

// get the items set inside of the do while loop.

// The system print out values are empty. 
System.out.printf(salesID + " you entered a total of: " + totalItems + "With a total sales of $%15.2f" + totalSales);
```